# How do I fix my bump map being messed up from certain angles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shaders, bump

For some context, I'm trying to turn my profile picture into a spinning coin GIF. I made a bump map and stuff, so it looks kind of 3d, but it seems to get messed up from certain viewing angles.

[image]

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/te28i.jpg) is a GIF of what I'm talking about.

Comment: I think it's because I had previously subdivided it a massive amount to try to get displacement to work. Currently trying to dissolve half the vertices.

Answer (score 3):

You should plug the texture into the Height input, not Normal.